# Why are the letters U, V and W used in AC motors to represent the windings?

Tags: motor, three-phase

I am connecting up an AC motor and was wondering if this labeling system was representative of something? Or just another set of letter like X,Y,Z?

I could not find any information regarding this in [IEC 60034-8, 
Rotating electrical machines – Part 8: Terminal markings and direction of 
rotation](https://law.resource.org/pub/in/bis/S05/is.iec.60034.8.2002.pdf) or a brief search of google, forums etc.

Comment: Well some people use A,B, and C, just convention I assume

Comment: Then of course R,Y,B is used for power phases in some cases.

Comment: It is just a convention, typically a world wide convention.  For things like drives, the convention is RST for supply, UVW for output to motor.  Motor leads may be labeled XYZ as well.  There are many such conventions, In the US, the past 'standard' was L1/L2/L3 for incoming, T1/T2/T3 for outgoing and motors.

Comment: In conclusion: L1 L2 L3 or R S T to input electrical energy. U V W for entry into the electric machines, either transformers or electric motors. Finally X Y Z to the end of the windings of electric motors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The letters are "representative of something"

To assist in providing an international standard the International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC) created that IEC 60034-8 standard. 
**"Terminal markings and direction of rotation"**

An electrical machine compliant to 60034-8 will ensure that clockwise rotation of the drive shaft will occur for positive electrical phase sequence U-V-W.

Thus if you were to wire such a machine upto a distribution labeled A-B-C and these electrical phases were A leading B, leading C... you would have the expected mechanical rotation

is it "just another set of letters"? you could say they arbitrarily chose that sequence, a sequence that is just as good as any other BUT they assigned a specific meaning to it and a meaning that is internationally recognised.

MotorA from supplier A and MotorB from supplier B being compliant to this reg & meeting the customer requirements would be drop-in replacements that would minimise any unexpected mechanical rotation

Comment: Complete speculation for why choose U-V-W over, say, A-B-C or X-Y-Z: U-V-W all sort-of-in-a-vague-way look like loops/coils of wire...

Answer (score 0):

In normative for manufacture electrical motors there exist two standards: DIN convention (Europe) and NEMA (American countries).

In normative DIN use for terminal leads the letters U, V, W signify the coil head, and letters  X, Y, Z signify coil end.

For example, a two pole three phase motor has 6 nests, 3 coils per nest, and 6 leads.

The first head nest start letter  U --- (end nest) (one pole north) join end --- X terminal (one  pole south)  phase 1 north pole and south pole 180° elec grade.  Phase 2 is similar to phase 1, V head start ----- Y end head. Likewise, for Phase 3, W ----- Z.

Then we have input voltages of 208, 230 V

```
      DIN normative (50Hz)          NEMA (60 Hz)          
   1Ø(R)> (U)------ (X) terminal    L1> T1---T4
   1Ø(S)> (v)-------(Y) terminal    L2> T2---T5                             
   1Ø(T)> (w)-------(z) terminal    L3> T3---T6
```

Now, use for start or wey connection single voltage

For start connection join (X, Y, Z) and connect U (phase 1), V (phase2), W (phase3) and delta join (U, Z) phase 1, join (V,X) phase 2, join (W,Y) phase 3.

Normative DIN (German) uses the first letter U mean (or) V, W (electrical machinery) and (R) (S) (T) for electrical terminal phases of 120°.

Note that R is *not* Run, S is *not* Start, and T is *not* Time

If a motor has 12 lead terminals:

```
    (U1 ----- X1) (V1----Y1) (W1----Z1)
    (U2 ----- X2) (V2----Y2) (W2----Z2)
```

Comment: why is this downvoted?